# Upgrading the Earthquake spell

Tags: clash-of-clans

Whats the point of upgrading the earthquake spell.

It is going to damage walls and buildings. However It is intended to be used for **breaking walls**.

Level 1 earthquake spell takes 4 spells for the walls to be destroyed,
on the other hand the Level 4 earthquake spell takes 4 spells to do the same.

**Strictly speaking of task of breaking walls.**

dark elixir spent in the research  =  30,000 + 60,000 + 90,000  = **180,000 Dark elixir**.

also considering the cost(Dark elixir) increase per spell is from 125 to 180 = **55 dark elixir**.

You spend **180,000 + 55 times number of spells created of dark elixir** more than you could have spent without upgrading it

So basically you are paying more amount of dark elixir for doing same amount of damage to walls.

Is there any point in upgrading the earthquake spell ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: because they do more damage.

Long answer:
While it does always take 4 quake spells to destroy walls, they also do damage to other buildings. Having an upgraded quake spell will allow you to do more damage to the buildings (other than storages) that are within the radius of the spell. While this may not be a lot more damage, on some of the tougher bases, the extra damage may be the difference in getting those buildings/defenses destroyed. The other reason is that while using 4 quake spells to destroy walls is popular, it is not the only strategy that uses quake spells. Another common one is to use 1 quake spell and 2 lightning spells to destroy an air defense, and if you quake spells aren't a high enough level, the combined damage may not be enough to destroy the air defense.